# Nodejs race condition for database insert and update

Tags: node.js, sql-server, transactions

I am using Nodejs with SQL Server database. I am using [this node-mssql](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql) package for writing queries from Nodejs.

I have a route which has a if condition and query structure as below:

```
let checkPartExists = await pool.query(`Select * from Parts WHERE partID = ${partID}`);
if (checkPartExists.recordset.length == 0){
   await pool.query(`INSERT INTO Parts(PartID, Quantity) VALUES(${partID}, ${quantity})`)
}
else{
   await pool.query(`UPDATE Parts SET Quantity = ${quantity} WHERE PartID = ${partID}`)
}
```

Now, if the single threaded Nodejs didn't have any event loop, I could safely assume that this would always work. But I know that that is not the case. I just had an instance where the same partID has been inserted twice.

My understanding is that:

1. User 1 makes a post request to that route
2. It executes the select query, finds that this partID does not exist in the parts table and reaches the insert portion
3. However, before it finishes with the insert User 2 (or maybe the same user) makes a post request and the select query is executed which also thinks that a part with that partID does not exist.

This will insert the same partID twice. Is this called a race condition? How do I prevent such situation?

I know I can make `PartID` a unique key in the database and throw an error when this happens, but I feel like there has to be a way of handling this through code as well.

Please let me know how you guys/girls are handling such situations.

Answer (score 0):

This is a job for a [Transaction](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql#transaction).  Something like this.

```js
const transaction = new sql.Transaction()
await transaction.begin()
const request = new sql.Reqest(transaction)
let checkPartExists = await request.query(`
     Select * from Parts WHERE partID = ${partID}`);
if (checkPartExists.recordset.length == 0){
   await request.query(`INSERT INTO Parts(PartID, Quantity) VALUES(${partID}, ${quantity})`)
} else {
   await request.query(`UPDATE Parts SET Quantity = ${quantity} WHERE PartID = ${partID}`)
}
await transaction.commit()
```

This serializes access to the table. Transactions are the standard way of avoiding race conditions.

Comment: But I read that the select query even inside the transaction does not lock the table. So if two processes hit the select part at the same time we still have the race condition. In the above case as soon as it reaches insert it locks the entire table so I guess it minimizes the race condition but does not solve it

Comment: I am sure you will find a transaction solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

If only one cluster of node.js application is running, then [async-mutex](https://www.npmjs.com/package/async-mutex) can be the solution. If you are running multiple clusters then [distributed deadlocking](https://martin.kleppmann.com/2016/02/08/how-to-do-distributed-locking.html) could be a solution.

Mutex is a design pattern so the resource can not be shared among instances.